# AndroidX: Error at setting setLifeCycleOwner for binding

Tags: android, androidx, android-jetpack

[image]

I am trying out androidx package(jetpack) and using for mvvm live data pattern. So, as part of that, setting the lifecycleowner for databinding in the  androidx.fragment.app.Fragment, **getting error like 
Required android.arch.lifecycle.LifeCycleOwner,

found androidx.lifecycle.LifeCycleOwner**

Comment: You appear to be using a mix of the Support Library and AndroidX. Somehow, data binding is using the Support Library. What version of the Android Gradle Plugin are you using? You can find that in your top-level `builld.gradle` file. For example, `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'`. Also, does your module's `build.gradle` specify a `buildToolsVersion`?

Comment: Using the classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1' and didn't specify the buildToolsVersion. What changes can i make to fix this issue?

Comment: I am not certain -- I have not seen this behavior before. I do not know how the data binding code decides whether to code-generate for the Support Library or AndroidX. Particularly if you are using Android Studio 3.4.1 or newer (the latest production build), you might try upgrading your Android Gradle Plugin to 3.4.1, then do a Build > Clean Project and Build > Rebuild Project from the Android Studio main menu, and see if you get the proper code generation.

Comment: I upgraded to 3.4.1 , cleaned the build and rebuild it... but no luck:(

Comment: Can you include your [gradle.properties file](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/#properties-files) or let us know if it is empty?

Answer (score 0):

It's too late but this is for reference who come across the same question and want to know what to do.

```
binding.setLifecycleOwner {viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle}
```